# Doctrine 2 query cache

Tags: doctrine-orm

My caching folder with Doctrine 2 gets filled up with thousands of folders which seem to contain the translated SQL queries for all doctrine actions that are performed. In-code, there are no explicit caching commands on my DQL-queries. Almost all DQL contains some variable part based on user actions, mostly some filtering in the WHERE-clause. I like the concept of caching the translation process, but it seems that queries are handled as a whole, rendering caching pointless as many queries are unique.

As I'm fairly new to Doctrine, there must be something I'm missing. Can somebody give me some directions on how to get the query caching working properly?

Also, clear-cache on the Doctrine command-line does not remove these folders, I delete them manually, what could that mean?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: Uh, do you possibly mean the log file? Under which path are these files generated? How are they named? Can you post a sample from such a file?

Comment: No I mean the directory that I set to be the caching directory in the config. Folder names look like the result of some hash function, each with 3 or 4 levels deep, with similar names. In the deepest folder there's a single file named dc2_[some longer hash name].doctrinecache.data. In it there's a serialized Doctrine\ORM\Query\ParserResult object, which has, among others, a SQL-query.

Comment: Ok, I see. I always thought D2 caches only when explicitely told so, but I'm not exactly an expert on Doctrine. Hope that someone else has a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters values do not affect Doctrine's query cache. Only one cache entry will be created for:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyBundle\Entity\User u WHERE u.id = :id');
```

Regardless how many times you will call it with different values:

```
$query->setParameters('id' => 1)->getResult();
$query->setParameters('id' => 2)->getResult();
<...>
```

So either this is not query cache, or you are not using [parameters binding](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query).

Comment: Do you know how to apply this to dynamic WHERE-clauses with a variable amount of AND's? Can't find anything about this and my attempts result in syntax errors.

Comment: This can be solved with a [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

I've been writing and API recently, which had optional parameters for querying objects, and it helped me. This is how it looks like: http://pastebin.com/XNyGa1X4

I've cut it out of context (environment is Symfony2 + Doctrine), but should be enough as an example of dealing with complex conditions.